# How to `command file.txt OR another_file.txt` in CLI (bash/zsh)

Tags: bash, terminal, command-line-interface, zsh

Is it possible to run a command with either `file.txt` as an argument or, if `file.txt` doesn't exist, with `another_file.txt`?

To make my request more realistic, I'd like to run VSCode with workspace file by default or, if workspace file doesn't exist, with `.` (current folder), something like:

```sh
code *.code-workspace OR .
```

If `*.code-workspace` exists, then the command should be equivalent to `code *.code-workspace`, otherwise the commend should be equivalent to `code .`

Is it possible in `bash` or `zsh`? (I'm using `zsh` + `oh-my-zsh`)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried? Then edit your question and please post what have you tried. Why doesn't it work? So your question is how to do it or how to do it in a "elegant way"?

Comment: I tried the custom function with if-else, and it works. But I wonder is there any elegant way to perform the same?

Comment: What would you do if there were more than one workspace file in the current directory?

Comment: @tom-fenech run `code` with the first match

Comment: If it is just two files, I can't think of a solution which looks particularily short. If I need this feature often, I would just write a shell script (or function), which iterates over its arguments and prints the first one to stdout which corresponds to an existing file. Once this script is written, you don't need any complicated `if` logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash you can use `nullglob` to expand wildcards (like `*`) to nothing if there is no match. Then put everything into an array and retrieve the first entry. Note that `$array` is the same as the first array entry `${array[0]}`.

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
files=(*.code-workspace .)
code "$files"
```

Above code starts `code firstMatchOf.code-workspace` if there is a file ending with `.code-workspace` and `.` if there is no such file.

For `zsh` you can do the same by replacing `shopt -s nullglob` with `setopt null_glob`.

Note that above approach only works with wildcards. `files=(a b); code "$files"` will call `code a` even if `a` does not exist. Here you could use the following function instead, which should work in every case:

```
#! /bin/sh
firstExisting() {
    set -- "$@" . # ensure termination 
    while ! [ -e "$1" ]; do
        shift
    done
    printf %s\\n "$1"
}
```

Usage example:

```
code "$(firstExisting *.code-workspace .)"
```

or just

```
code "$(firstExisting *.code-workspace)"
```

… as `.` is the default in case none of the arguments existed. `shopt -s nullglob` is not needed here.

Comment: @LimonMonte Yeah, `shopt` is a `bash` thing. I think in `zsh` it is `setopt null_glob`. Anyways, the second approach should work in all POSIX shells and also work for non-wildcards.

Comment: `[ -a "$1" ]` that `-a` is something strange, you meant `-f` or `-r` right?

Comment: `-a` is a non-standard `bash` extension equivalent to `-e`.

Comment: Oops. Thank you KamilCuk and Chepner for pointing this out. I corrected the script to be POSIX conform.